# Where should I set my working directory for this code using excel files

Tags: r

I am very new to coding and need help with this script I'm supposed to use. I am supposed to be taking Excel files and running it through the code, but I am very lost. How do I set my working directory? Do I set it to the file folder I have on my computer that contains the Excel files I want to use?

```
library("readxl")
#batch <- read_excel('Statistics-Batch_13-Day1_Openfiled_02-12-2018.xlsx', skip=0, col_names = FALSE)
#indx_inarena <- grepl('In Arena', batch[5,])
#indx_cnt_cum_dur <- grepl('In zone', batch[1,]) & grepl('Arena / Center-point', batch[2,]) & grepl('Cumulative Duration', batch[3,])

batch_list <- list.files('./rawfiles/',pattern='Stat*')
```

Comment: Comment the code, what do you think each line is doing? Most of it is commented out but the last line, will generate a list of files in the rawfiles folder that start with Stat. But the ./ means it starts from your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Set your working directory to one level about the rawfiles folder that contains your Excel files.

```
setwd("/home/myProjects/ReadMultipleExcelFiles/")

batch_list <- list.files('./rawfiles/', pattern = 'Stat*')
```

Note that this is equivalent to passing the full path as follows:

```
batch_list <- list.files('/home/myProjects/ReadMultipleExcelFiles/rawfiles/', pattern = 'Stat*')
```

Now batch_list will contain the list of files you need to process.